# How to display data sent from android app to a php on an html page?

Tags: php, android, html

I am really confused about how to send data from my android app to a website. I am thinking of using php to get data from android and send data to the html page. I am aware of sending data through php to a mysql server. I am unsure about the php and html file that I have to develop here. I need the data to be displayed in some textbox in my html page.

Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by sending data to HTML page from php, html can not recieve data. Instead you can use a php page to do it.

Android code:

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("PHP_PAGE_ADDRESS");
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", "abc"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data1", "def"));
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
$data =$_GET['data'];
$data1 = $_GET['data1'];
?>
<form>
Data: <input type="text" name="firstname" value = <?php echo $data; ?> ><br>
Data1: <input type="text" name="firstname" value = <?php echo $data1; ?> >
</form>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to send your data in json format. 
Actually i am not aware of android app.
But i think it is possible to send data in json format and you can easily receive in php by

```
json_decode($encoded_json_var);
```

Comment: Yes i know how to receive data in php from android. What i want is how to send this data in php to a html form???