# How to send data from android app to web app PHP and display in html page?

Tags: php, android, html

I was searching for a way to send a data from android app to PHP and display it in an HTML. I saw the same question and try it [How to display data sent from android app to a php on an html page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18328663/how-to-display-data-sent-from-android-app-to-a-php-on-an-html-page). But now it does not work.

My android app feature is to input firstname, lastname and address. After completing the input, click button save and then redirect to the web browser and display the input details. This is what I've tried.

Android App

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        savebtn = findViewById(R.id.savebtn);
        editTextFName   = findViewById(R.id.editTextFName);
        editTextLName   = findViewById(R.id.editTextLName);
        editTextAddress = findViewById(R.id.editTextAddress);

        savebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String val_Fname = editTextFName.getText().toString();
                String val_Lname = editTextLName.getText().toString();
                String val_Addr = editTextAddress.getText().toString();

                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/webdisplay/index.php");
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                
                try{
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("android_Fname", val_Fname);
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("android_Lname", val_Lname));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("android_Addr", val_Addr));
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error"+e.toString());
                }

                redirectTo("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/webdisplay/index.php");

            }
        });
    }
```

PHP

```
<?php
    $dataFname = $_GET['android_Fname'];
    $dataLname = $_GET['android_Lname'];
    $dataAddr = $_GET['android_Addr'];
?>

<html>
<body>

<div>
    <?php echo $dataFname; ?>
    <?php echo $dataLname; ?>
    <?php echo $dataAddr; ?>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Reference: https://www.folkstalk.com/tech/how-to-display-data-sent-from-android-app-to-a-php-on-an-html-page-solutions/

Comment: Your question was already answered in this forum [Forum][1] I hope it may help you


  [1]: https://www.folkstalk.com/tech/how-to-display-data-sent-from-android-app-to-a-php-on-an-html-page-solutions/

Comment: `and then redirect to the web browser and display the input details.` That is not possible with another app or with another call to the same url as then you get the html form elements empty just like when you called it for the first time. (Why didn't you tell?). No. Your page is in `HttpResponse response`. You could display it in a WebView.

Comment: @Ademkriouane Thank you but it doesn't work too. It is the same answer on this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18328663/how-to-display-data-sent-from-android-app-to-a-php-on-an-html-page

Comment: you seem to send POST request yet you try to read `$_GET` instead of `$_POST`

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I tried to change it now to `$_POST` but it is still empty no data is showing

Comment: @blackapps Is there no other way to display the android input, receive it in php and display in HTML webpage? just without using database..

Comment: You are not using a database.

Comment: @blackapps yes I don't use database. I know it is possible to save the input android data to database first by PHP backend and then query and display to HTML. But without database what is the other option?

Comment: That i already told you. Use response.

Comment: @blackapps Can you elaborate on the answer how to do it? and not to display in a webview because I have some features need to put on my PHP HTML in the browser.

Comment: What do you wanna put? And why dont you just wanna display the response? In a toast. In  a textview. Or in whatever.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250061/discussion-between-jba-and-blackapps).

Comment: @blackapps my main application is on the web, so I can't display it in a toast etc. My main goal was to display the android input to the webpage.

Comment: So your Android app is on the web? How did you manage that?

Comment: @blackapps from the web it will click a button to redirect to the app, and on the app it will input some data and then click submit, it will redirect back to the web then display the inputed data *I know it is quite complicated process but it is a project requirement*

Comment: A button on the web? I cannot imagine what that would be. And what is 'redirect to the app'? All requirements? Who told you that?